# Assets: pick a random one of the assets in this entry

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, random

If my client attaches 4 images to an Assets-field for an entry, how would I get a random one of those images? I was hoping something along these lines:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='types'}
    {type_map_icon limit='1' orderby='random'}

    {/type_map_icon}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Where `{type_map_icon}` is the Assets-field which holds the 4 images. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad! Assumed orderby='random' but the parameter = sort='random'!

Comment: Probably worth emailing P&T about this, it's strange that it's inconsistent with every other EE plugin.